# Configure ffmpeg/ffserver in openshift

Tags: ffmpeg, openshift, ffserver

I've managed to setup ffserver and stream videos on laptop.
How can I do the same using openshift.

I wanted to install ffserver and ffmpeg in openshift and stream videos.
Googled few links nothing seems to be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can install rpm's inside your gear you'll need to compile everything from source. Looks like a solution was presented in this thread: https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/ffmpeg